# Gmail API attachment preview not working after insert call

Tags: gmail-api, google-workspace

I am using the .NET client library to perform an [users.messages.insert](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/insert) call to a Gmail mailbox. I am inserting a MIME message with an attachment by encoding it into URLSafeBase64 and adding it to Message.Raw.

This is how an email with an attachment preview should look like:
[image: Email with an attachment]

This is how the inserted email looks like (We have no indication that there is an attachment in this email):
[image: Email with an attachment inserted]

But when I open the email, the attachment exists and is displaying properly:
[image: Inside the inserted email]

My question is why does the insert call not preserve the attachment preview in the main Gmail UI page?

```
public void InsertMessage(Message message)
{
    string functionName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
    
    UsersResource.MessagesResource.InsertRequest request = GoogleService.GetGmailService(AuthenticatedUser.SMTPAddress).Users.Messages.Insert(message, "me");
    
    request.InternalDateSource = Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.InsertRequest.InternalDateSourceEnum.DateHeader;
    
    Message response = null;
    
    try
    {
        response = request.Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Console.Log.WriteLine("Exception thrown while inserting message");
    }
}
```

The Message in the function above has the following fields populated:

- message.Raw
- message.LabelIds
- message.Snippet
- message.Id

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I edited the post to include my code for the message insert.